# how to invoke bash script with aws lambda function in python?

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda

I want to invoke a bash script with name `myScript.sh` in a newly created lambda function.

Step 1: I created a lambda function with name `myLambda.py` and the source code like:

```
import subprocess
print("start") 
subprocess.call("./myScript.sh")"
```

Step 2: Create a bash script with name `myScript.sh` under the same path with `myLambda.py`

Step 3: Click the test button and got the response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: './myScript.sh'"
}
```

Anybody knows how to deal with the permission denied issue in aws lambda function env?

Since the files are added as the guideline in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/code-editor.html, it's not helpful to use linux command "chmod +x " to change the file permission.

It's resolved by move myScript.sh to /tmp folder and add permission change command:

```py
subprocess.run(["chmod", "+x", "/tmp/myScript.sh"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute scripts that don't have execute permission. You can supply execute permissions using some variant of:

```
chmod +x /somepath/myScript.sh
```

You can run this using your current subprocess approach. Run chmod before you run myScript.sh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I add the myScript.sh with the guideline in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/code-editor.html. I don't know how to change the file permission over there since it's not saved in the local machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. Got read-only file system error after using "subprocess.run(["chmod", "+x", "/var/task/myScript.sh"])". It looks the file should under /tmp folder. Fix it by moving the file under /tmp folder.

Comment: Can you show your complete myLambda.py, this isnt working for me.